# How to fix : unable to reconnect with Empathy / telepathy to a specific IRC channel after computer hard reboot ? Others channels are OK

Tags: empathy, irc, telepathy

After a crach of my computer I reboot it.Empathy started to auto-connect to the set IRC channels, except to #gaia on irc.mozilla.org . Other channels on the same server works well.

- I'm unable to manualy join #gaia channel (clikng on a link or try to join by the menu item)
- '#gaia' channel is well listed on the "Join channel" window.
- I tried to remove logs and any hidden file related to Empathy & telepathy.
- I deleted and reset my IRC account in ubuntu accounts
- I deleted and reset the mozilla IRC server
- '#gaia' still not working, others do.

How can I fix that to be able to use again Empathy/telepathy for any irc channel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by a change server side : need of Authentication + password

I had to register :

1. Connect to the irc server with my nickname
2. Register that nickname with a password and an email
3. Set my IRC client to identify at connexion

People from others mozilla channels helped me to do all that.

On Ubuntu, as Online Accounts in settings pannel keeps you connected to the server (but not chatrooms) until you stop allowing it to use the account, you cannot use an other IRC client, even if you closed Empathy/telepathy.